# Não consigo atribuir um valor dentro da minha Label a partir de uma Lista

Tags: c#

Bom dia, primeiramente gostaria de dizer que sou iniciante e estou com dúvida na hora de atribuir um valor à propriedade `Text` de uma `Label` a partir de uma lista criada com informação obtida a partir de um arquivo `txt`.

Segue o código:

```
namespace BetaTeste
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            List<Planta> plantas = new List<Planta>();

            using (StreamReader arquivo = File.OpenText(@"C:\Estados\Banco de Estados.txt"))
            {
                string linha;
                while ((linha = arquivo.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    var espaçoArquivo = linha.Split(';');

                    var planta = new Planta();
                    planta.Local = espaçoArquivo[0];
                    planta.Conexao = espaçoArquivo[1];

                    plantas.Add(planta);
                }

            }

            foreach (Planta result in plantas)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(result.Local);
            }
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FrmBase formb = new FrmBase();

            switch (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim())
            {
                case "CT":
                    formb.Show(); 

                    // aqui está a dúvida
                    // formb.lblLocal.Text = ;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Planta
{
    public string Local { get; set; }
    public string Conexao { get; set; }

    public void Pesquisa()
    {

    }
}

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public partial class FrmBase : Form
{
    public FrmBase()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

O objetivo é preencher a `Label` com o valor de uma propriedade da classe `Planta`, mas não sei como consigo obter informação das classes listadas nos `items` da `ComboBox`.

A `label` que quero atribuir o valor é a `formb.lblLocal` (linha em comentário).

Comment: Qual é sua dúvida ao certo? Para atribuir o valor à _Label_ basta colocar o valor no _Text_, como já está no seu código...

Comment: Bom dia João, a minha duvida seria colocar um item da minha lista ali dentro dependendo da escolha do usuário do combox

Comment: Que texto pretende colocar na _Label_? É uma das popriedades da classe _Planta_?

Comment: Exatamente João, eu quero colocar a propriedade Local na lblLocal e a propriedade conexão na lblConexão dependendo do caso do switch

Comment: Penso que com a edição efetuada, a questão já está clara o suficiente para ser retirada a marca de "pendente".

Comment: Muito obrigado João sou novo nessas coisas, agradeço sua compreensão em editar minha pergunta

Comment: Acho que entendi onde voce quer chegar. Você já popula seu combobox com a propriedade "Local" de cada Planta. Para obter a string do item selecionado basta obter o comboboxitem selecionado (ComboBoxItem item = combobox1.selectedItem as ComboBoxItem). Em seguida pegar o seu content (item.Content.Tostring()). Por fim, para setar essa string na sua label basta fazer: label.Content = stringAqui.

Comment: Filipe poderia demonstrar em uma linha de código?

Comment: Pedi para reabrir por ser mais fácil colocar código, mas a solução passa por fazer o seguinte (sem quaisquer validações): _formb.lblLocal.Text = ((Planta)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Local;_

Comment: Usando essa solução João aparece isso aqui na hora de depurar o código: System.InvalidCastException: 'Não é possível converter um objeto do tipo 'System.String' no tipo 'BetaTeste.Planta'.'

Comment: Ha, claro, não está a ser atribuída a instância da classe _Planta_ aos _items_ da _ComboBox_. Faça o seguinte, no _foreach_ que usa para atribuir o valor do _item_ coloque da seguinte forma: **comboBox1.Items.Add(result);**, depois, fora do _foreach_ coloque: **comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Local";**. Penso que assim o resto do código já irá funcionar, e dessa forma consegue obter qualquer informação da class _Planta_.

Comment: O código ate depura, mas quando escolho os items da combox não chama o outro formulário

Comment: Ao invés de colocar **switch (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim())** coloque: **switch (((Planta)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Local)**.

Comment: Obrigado João o código esta depurando e funcionando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui está a sua resposta corretamente estruturada e otimizada :)

```
namespace BetaTeste
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();

            using (StreamReader arquivo = File.OpenText(@"C:\Estados\Banco de Estados.txt"))
            {
                string linha;

                while ((linha = arquivo.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    var espaçoArquivo = linha.Split(';');

                    comboBox1.Items.Add(new Planta()
                    {
                        Local = espaçoArquivo[0]
                        Conexao = espaçoArquivo[1]
                    });                     
                }
            }
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FrmBase formb = new FrmBase();

            if(comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                Planta planta = (Planta)comboBox1.SelectedItem;

                switch (planta.Local)
                {
                    case "CT":
                        formb.Show(); 
                        formb.lblLocal.Text = planta.Local;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Planta
{
    public string Local { get; set; }
    public string Conexao { get; set; }

    public void Pesquisa() {}
}

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public partial class FrmBase : Form
{
    public FrmBase()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```